# Не удается получить количество постов по запросу get_posts в wodpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на `wordpress` и вывод постов определенной категории вида:

```
$myposts = get_posts( array(
    'category_name' => 'spring', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'orderby'     => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
) );
```

Сами посты выводятся без проблем и в `var_dump($myposts);` все отображается верно.

Теперь мне нужно получить количество постов запроса. Руководствуюсь [инструкцией](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties), но получаю и в первом и во втором результате `null` - почему?

```
$count = $myposts->post_count;
$count1 = $myposts->post_count;
var_dump($count,$count1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что надо использовать  [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Но конкретно в вашем случаи попробуйте:

```
$count = count($myposts);
```

Comment: просто один из самых авторитетных источников wp-kama https://wp-kama.ru/id_767/3-sposoba-postroeniya-tsiklov-v-wordpress.html советует `Самый удобный вариант выводить нужные записи в нужном порядке — это выводить их с помощью get_posts() (см. описание). get_posts() в 99% случаев полностью заменяет WP_Query()`

Comment: @Вася `get_posts` это тоже самое что и `WP_Query`. `get_posts` - `Это обертка класса WP_Query, т.е. функция понимает все параметры WP_Query.`.  А `get_posts` возвращает только записи и всё, больше ничего. Если надо чтобы методы WP_Query можно было использовать, тогда нужно использовать WP_Query.  Но в вашем случаи достаточно просто использовать функцию `count()`